# Android studio rendering doesn't match. TextView misplaced

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Current Task"
    android:id="@+id/currTask"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/currTask"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/currTask"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/currTask"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Started:"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/currTask"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/currTask" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Time Remaining:"
    android:id="@+id/timeRemain"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Next Task:"
    android:id="@+id/txtNxt"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeRemain"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timeRemain" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Remind"
    android:id="@+id/swtchRemind"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtNxt"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Done"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtNxt"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtNxt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Snooze"
    android:id="@+id/btnSnooze"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/swtchRemind"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/swtchRemind" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/tvTimeRemaining"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/timeRemain"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeRemain"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/swtchRemind"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/swtchRemind" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNxt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtNxt"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtNxt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="tst"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I have a problem with `textView6`. Android studio renders this whole thing (it's a tab which is inflated in `onCreate`) properly: `textView6` is under `txtNxt`. *But* in both my phone and the emulator (My phone runs android 4.4.2, and I've tried 4.4.4 and 4.2.2. Couldn't get the emulator for 5.0 to load), `testView4` is right below `textView6`, *which is right below* `currTask`.

I've tried deleting it and re-creating it, I've tried to copy-and-paste `textView4` and modify the field `android:layout_below`. Nothing works.

Also - the rendering shows both buttons on the same horizontal line, but on my phone and on the emulators, `button2` is a bit lower `btnSnooze`

the logcat:

```
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1381)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TimePicker.getHour, referenced from method com.example.sayals.mytodo.MainActivity.AddItm
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18737: Landroid/widget/TimePicker;.getHour ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 5% free 3921K/4088K, paused 5ms, total 8ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 50K, 4% free 4372K/4512K, paused 4ms, total 7ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.770MB for 2536932-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 6848K/6992K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb888d0c0, tid 1314
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

Any ideas?

I will note that the `target SDK version` is `19`, as it should be, but the `compile SDK version` is 23. I've tried changing it to 19 through the settings, but it didn't help, and even though It compiled, I got an error for these lines at `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

saying they don't match the `compile SDK version`. I haven't tried changing these, even though they seem relevant... probably should, but I'm guessing I need to download some relevant stuff using the SDK manager... I already have downloaded some SDK-related stuff for api level 19, but it still says it can't resolve the dependencies...

Comment: It works as expected on my phone. Are you sure the apk on your phone and emulator is the correct one, with the current layout?

Comment: Any debug info in logcat?

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung Nothing that seems relevant. I'll edit the post and add it

Comment: @MikeM. Yes. Can you tell me the settings you used? (Target SDK? SDK build tools? any other relevant information that might account for differences?

Comment: I don't think it would be the SDK version, since `RelativeLayout` has been around since version 1, but my defaults are `minSdkVersion 14` and `targetSdkVersion 21`. I ran it on a Samsung Galaxy S4, 1080 x 1920.